# Android disable scroll and click for listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a simple layout, a listview, and two icons for filtering and sorting options. When I click on the either of the two options I have a layout that is placed above the listview and covers only 60% of the screen thereby making the listview below it partially visible. What I want to achieve is to disable the scrolling for that listview also, none of the listview item should be clickable as long as the overlay is visible.

I tried using

```
setEnabled(false)
setClickable(false)
```

on the listview but it doesn't make any difference. What are other ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for disabling the parent scrollview

parentview.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

if the overlay is visible .

Comment: that would make it perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that the overlay will be on the whole screen.
Then, you can wrap the overlay with (vertical) linear layout with weights (to achieve 60%/40% ratio). In the linear layout, place your current overlay as the first child and as a second child put a transparent view that will block touch events. This way you won't need to do any modifications to the list view.

Comment: Why not make the filter option container a child of the overlay (you will need to make the overlay relative/frame layout). Have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: I took your suggestion, but instead of using transparent second child to block touch events, my semi transparent overlay mask does that work for me.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the scrolling you can use the **OnTouchListener()**

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            return true; // Indicates that this has been handled by you and will not be forwarded further.
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

OR

```
listView.setScrollContainer(false);
```

For disabling the click, In your custom ArrayAdapter override isEnabled method as following

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what if I want to enable clickability again?

Comment: "return true;" in isEnabled. You may use a boolean and return that based on your need.

Comment: if I am not wrong isEnabled would work when I am creating list initially, that is when I first load the list, I understand that in such a case isEnabled would work based on any condition I apply and set the view's clickability, but would it even work after the listview is already created and then after that on some user click action I wish to decide clickability? I am a bit confused on this front.